# Virtual Resolution for OS X

Tags: macos, resolution

Is there a solution for OS X that allows you to have virtual resolution (aka take my MacBook Air from 1366x768 to a higher res that scrolls).

Answer (score 0):

I think zoom does what you're looking for.

`Apple menu > System Preferences > Access > Zoom`

More Options will give you a slider that allows you to adjust the amount of magnification.

Comment: The OP is asking about adjusting the resolution past the maximum, not zooming